# Convert delimited string to combobox ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

Scenario:
-1 user selected
-user has many types
-type has many levels
user can only have 1 active level per type at a time but can pick which level

Datasource example (datacontent is dynamic):

```
UserID  Type   Level    
1       2      1,2,3
1       3      1,2,4
1       4      5,99,1
```

I already have a grid setup. I just cant work out how to create a combo with the levels split out.

Result basedon above would be that in row 1:
Userid/type fixed columns, column 3 needs to be combobox thats shows the relevant levels related to the current row id (i.e. row 1 combo would only show  1,2,3 as available selections), and so on for all rows.

Current code if needed

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding DOAProperty}" x:Key="possibilities"/>
</Grid.Resources>
<DataGrid 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="243" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="977"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding iecv}"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DivID" Binding="{Binding DivisionID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding DivisionName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="AuthLevels" Binding="{Binding AuthLevels}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="SeletedAuthLevel" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource possibilities} }" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedAuthID, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="AuthLevels" DisplayMemberPath="AuthLevels" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Maybe a solution is to retrieve this row and split it in a List<> or ObservableCollection. Then bind it to a column.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the data is dynamic, ideally was after something to dynamically convert the string to a combo, i'm having a think about your approach, essentially it would be itterative at time of creation which will likely work, its just a case of how to do this?.....

Comment: ok - if this wasnt mvvm/wpf this would be so simple, cant use your approach as cant interact with the grid at row/col level iteratively from model view :( at least not that ive found

Comment: IValueConverter, easy as pie.